# JQuery hide a div inside an array of children()

Tags: jquery, fade

I have the next array:

```
var Images = $('.cs_slider').children();
```

Checked the array and it is not empty.

The array contains divs, each one of them, has another div inside it.

I would like to use `fadeOut()` on the inside div (`.info`) of the next image that slides.

I tried using this, but it doesn't work (Started with JQuery a month ago):

```
Images[CurrentImage].('.info').fadeOut();
```

`CurrentImage` is surely an integer.

The effect should run only once, so looping is not what I meant. Any ideas what's wrong with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.info', Images[CurrentImage]).fadeOut();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
$(Images[CurrentImage]).find('.info').fadeOut();
```

Note that `Images[CurrentImage]`<sup>1</sup> is a DOM element, not a jQuery object.

---

<sup>1</sup> *NB: those are bad variable names - upper case is normally reserved for classes*

Comment: @mgraph I don't follow you.  He does say that `Images` is actually an array of divs, not img tags.

Comment: sorry the var name is confusing, didn't pay attention

Answer (score 0):

```
Images.eq(CurrentImage).find('.info').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
($Images[CurrentImage]).find('.info').fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

More of your source code would help, but it looks like your not using the selector properly.  Try something like this instead:

$( Images[CurrentImage] + ' .info ).fadeOut();

This will end up looking something like this to jQuery:

$( 'div_name .info' ).fadeOut();

Again, next time please let us see more of your source code or start up a JSFiddle

Comment: Yep, I see what you mean now.  Thought he had an array of div names, not the actual DOM element.